# Sockets con hilos

Tags: java, eclipse, hilos, socket

> Estoy haciendo pruebas con sockets con hilos y quiero que cada nuevo cliente que se conecta al servidor sea atendido por un hilo y que en el servidor aparezca el número de sockets en cuestión. Alguna sugerencia?

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainCliente extends Thread {
    static long clientesAtendidos = 0;
    static long hilosActivos = 0;
    Socket socket;

    public MainCliente(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
   }


   synchronized long clientesAtendidos() {
       return clientesAtendidos;
   }

   synchronized void iniciando() {
       clientesAtendidos++;
       hilosActivos++;
   }

   synchronized void terminando() {
       hilosActivos--;
   }

    public void run() {
         iniciando();
         try {
            despacha();
         } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            //aqui manejas la excepción 
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
         }
         finally {
            terminando();
         }
     }

   protected void despacha() throws Exception {

       hilosActivos++;  //etc etc
       //aquí tienes el Socket con el que estás conectado al cliente para comunicarte
       //con el cliente
       //...
       socket.close();
    }
}

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

//  Clase  base Conexíon (de la que hereda MainCliente y MainServidor)
public class Conexion
{
    private final int PORT = 8080;   // Puerto común para la conexión
    private final String HOST = "localhost";   // Host para la conexión
    protected ServerSocket ss;   // Socket del servidor
    protected Socket cs; // Socket del cliente

    // Constructor
    public Conexion(String tipo) throws IOException     
    { 
        if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("servidor"))
        {
            ss = new ServerSocket(PORT); // Se crea el socket para el servidor en puerto 1234
            cs = new Socket(); // Socket para el cliente
        }
        else
        {
            cs = new Socket(HOST, PORT); // Socket para el cliente en localhost en puerto 1234
        }
    }
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MainServidor extends Conexion //Se hereda de conexión para hacer 
uso de los sockets y demás
{
    int idCliente = 0;
    protected String mensajeEntrantes; 
    protected DataOutputStream salidaCliente; // Flujo de datos de salida

    public MainServidor() throws IOException{   super("servidor");
    }

    // Método para iniciar el servidor
    public void startServer() throws Exception
    {
       //Nota que no estamos cerrando ServerSocket aquí ya que el método
       //es iniciaServidor. Creo que se debería cerrar en otra parte.

      while(true) { // ???              
          System.out.println("Esperando..."); // Esperando conexión
          Socket cs = ss.accept();
          //aquí se conecta un cliente al server socket y muestra
          //el mensaje que se ha conectado un cliente, y despacha
          //al cliente en un hilo individual (DespachaClientes)
          idCliente++;
          System.out.println("Cliente " + idCliente + " en línea");

          MainCliente hilo = new MainCliente(cs);
          hilo.start();
          System.out.println("clientes atendidos:"+hilo.clientesAtendidos());
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estoy editando la respuesta para que cuando se conecte un cliente al servidor se muestre mensaje. Avísame si tienes mas dudas.  Saludos

Puedes crear una clase que despache a los clientes en un hilo:

```
public class DespachaClientes extends Thread {
   static long clientesAtendidos = 0;
   static long hilosActivos = 0;
   Socket socket;

   public DespachaClientes(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
   }


   synchronized long clientesAtendidos() {
       return clientesAtendidos;
   }
   synchronized long hilosActivos {
       return hilosActivos;
   }        
   synchronized void iniciando() {
       clientesAtendidos++;
       hilosActivos++;
   }
   synchronized void terminando() {
       hilosActivos--;
   }

    public void run() {
         iniciando();
         try {
            despacha();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            //aqui manejas la excepción 
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
         }
         finally {
            terminando();
         }
   }
   protected void despacha() throws Exception {

       idCliente++;  //etc etc
       //aquí tienes el Socket con el que estás conectado al cliente para comunicarte
       //con el cliente
       //...
       socket.close();
    }
  }
```

Y cambiárias tu método para iniciar el servidor más o menos así:

```
public void startServer() throws Exception
{
   //Nota que no estamos cerrando ServerSocket aquí ya que el método
   //es iniciaServidor. Creo que se debería cerrar en otra parte.

  while(true) { // ???              
      System.out.println("Esperando..."); // Esperando conexión
      Socket cs = ss.accept();
      //aquí se conecta un cliente al server socket y muestra
      //el mensaje que se ha conectado un cliente, y despacha
      //al cliente en un hilo individual (DespachaClientes)
      idCliente++;
      System.out.println("Cliente " + idCliente + " en línea");

      DespachaClientes hilo = new DespachaClientes(cs);
      hilo.start();
      System.out.println("clientes atendidos:"+hilo.clientesAtendidos());
      System.out.println("hilos de clientes activos:"+hilo.hilosActivos());
  }
}
```

En base a la edición que hiciste prueba lanzando la aplicación desde esta clase,
tiene un método main para que la puedas ejecutar.

```
/**
  Aquí generas varios hilos que simulan conexiones de clientes.
  Luego lanzas el servidor.
**/
public class LanzaServer {

    public static class ConexionCliente extends Conexion {
        public ConexionCliente() throws IOException {
           super("cliente");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       for (int cliente = 0; cliente <8; cliente++) {
          Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ConexionCliente conexion = new ConexionCliente();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }            
            }
           };
           Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
           thread.start();
       }
       MainServidor ms = new MainServidor();
       ms.startServer();
  }
```

Comment: No entiendo Alberto, lo que quiero es que cada vez que se conecte un cliente. aparezca en el socket servidor el mensaje: se ha conectado el cliente número x.

Comment: @Juan acabo de editar respuesta, favor de revisarla y agregar comentarios si todavía no te queda claro.

Comment: Sigue dando error el  static long hilosActivos = 0;

Comment: @Juan puedes poner el código como lo has cambiado para verlo.

Comment: Ya lo he puesto

Comment: ¿el error que mencionas es de compilación o de ejecución? y ¿que mensaje de error te muestra?

Comment: Este es el error que me da: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

Comment: Juan pon el método main o donde lanzas el servidor y los clientes. Muestras el error, pero no muestras el código que lo provoca.

Comment: lo puse arriba en el código

Comment: Juan edité mi respuesta para poner una clase que lanza el servidor y varias conexiones de clientes. Intenta correr esa clase. Es clase LanzaServer